add_rewrite_rule but no value in the get_query_var
I'm trying to clean the URL in WordPress.
instead of this www.website.com/mypage/?myvariable=fr
I want to have this www.website.com/fr/mypage/
The redirection works well, but I can not get the value I put in the URL as a $_GET value.
In the first part I used add_rewrite_rule seems to work well. The redirection is OK.
function add_rewrite(){
    flush_rewrite_rules();
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'fr/([a-z0-9-]+)',
        'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&myvariable=fr',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'add_rewrite');

But I can not get the value of myvariable which looks empty
echo get_query_var("myvariable");
even if I use the following code
function add_query_vars($aVars) {
    $aVars[] = "myvariable";
    return $aVars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'add_query_vars');


try to add add_rewrite_tag('%myvariable%', "([^&]+)"); in init hook

thanks but adding add_rewrite_tag doesn't change the result

does anyone have any ideas?

Ok I found the solution :
I tried to acess to the value inside the functions.php file but it's not possible. I put the lines below in the template file and it works perfectly:
global $wp_query;
$myvariable = $wp_query->query_vars['myvariable'];
echo $myvariable;

